# Can´t center text in Syncfusion GridSummaryColumn

Tags: wpf, syncfusion, summary, sfdatagrid

I'm trying without sucess to center or position in other ways the text in the summary row of my Syncfusion SfDataGrid in WPF. I have the following structure:

```
 <syncfusion:SfDataGrid
        ...
        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
           ...
        </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.TableSummaryRows>
            <syncfusion:GridTableSummaryRow
                CalculationUnit="SelectedRows"
                Position="Top"
                ShowSummaryInRow="False">
                <syncfusion:GridSummaryRow.SummaryColumns>
                    <syncfusion:GridSummaryColumn
                        Name="SomaQuantidade"
                        Format="'{Sum:#.0}'"
                        MappingName="Quantidade"
                        SummaryType="DoubleAggregate"/>
                    ...
                </syncfusion:GridSummaryRow.SummaryColumns>
            </syncfusion:GridTableSummaryRow>
        </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.TableSummaryRows>
    </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
```

And it works fine, except the text is always left aligned in the column:

[image]

There´s no alignment property in `GridSummaryColumn` nor `GridTableSummaryRow` so I tried creating a `DataTemplate` for the `GridSummaryColumn`, with a textblock like this:

```
<TextBlox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ...}"/>
```

It also shows aligned to the left!
I couldn't find help for this in Syncfusion docs, so I would really appreciate if anyone could point me out anyway to get these summary texts aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding the `GridTableSummaryCell` Style and set the value of the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property. Refer to the below code snippet:

```
<Window.Resources>
 <Style TargetType="syncfusion:GridTableSummaryCell">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
 </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```